# JQuery: sumar valores con condiccion

Tags: php, jquery

como podria hacer la suma por estado ? tengo 3 estados, "PAGADO", "DEBE" y "ANULADO". Actualmente ya tengo el totalizado general.

Código para sumar.

```
var sum=0;
$('.subtotal').each(function() {  
 sum += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''), 10);  
}); 
$('#resultado_total').val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado esperado;

- Total Global (Ya esta hecho)
- Total Pagado
- Total Debe
- Total Anulado

gracis de antemano!

Comment: tendrías que capturar todos los `.pagado` y sumar el valor de lo que tiene al lado (div/span/td) a un `pagadoTotal` y luego lo mismo para los `.anulado` en `anuladoTotal` y asi

Comment: Hola JBAL27, por favor añade el html para crear un [mcve] y que podamos ver el problema en la propia pregunta y podamos ayudarte mejor. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero creamos un objeto con los tipos que necesitas:

```
const tipo = { tipo1: 'PAGADO', tipo2: 'ANULADO', tipo3: 'DEBE' };
```

Aquí un ejemplo para asignarle una clase a todos las filas de tu tabla que contentengan la palabra "PAGADO" que en nuestro caso es tipo1 de nuestro objeto.

```
$("#tablon-ed-edd-yeddy").find('tr:contains("' + tipo.tipo1 + '")')
             .attr('class', tipo.tipo1);
```

Luego simplemente buscamos y sumamos las filas que contengan la clase que le asignamos anteriormente.

```
var sumPagado = 0;
$('.PAGADO').each(function(){
  sumPagado += parseFloat($(this).closest("tr").find(':eq(1)').text().replace(',', '.'));
});
```

Despues ya puedes insertar ese valor en donde tu desees :).

```
$('#sumPagado').text(sumPagado.toFixed(2));
```

De esta manera puedes hacer con los demás tipos.

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando :

```js
const tipo = { tipo1: 'PAGADO', tipo2: 'ANULADO', tipo3: 'DEBE' };

$("#tablon-ed-edd-yeddy").find('tr:contains("' + tipo.tipo1 + '")')
             .attr('class', tipo.tipo1);

var sumPagado = 0;
$('.PAGADO').each(function(){
  sumPagado += parseFloat($(this).closest("tr").find(':eq(1)').text().replace(',', '.'));
});

$('#sumPagado').text(sumPagado.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tablon-ed-edd-yeddy">
  <thead>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>PAGADO</td>
      <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PAGADO</td>
      <td>250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ANULADO</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DEBE</td>
      <td>300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ANULADO</td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1>Total Pagado: <span id="sumPagado"></span></h1>
```